# LINQ SelectMany and Where extension method ignoring nulls

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-objects

I have the below example code, and I am interested to know how I can make this any cleaner, possibly through better use of `SelectMany()`. At this point the `QuestionList` property will not be null. All I want is a list of `answerRows` that are not `null`, but `Questions` can sometimes be `null` too.

```
IEnumerable<IQuestion> questions = survey.QuestionList
                    .Where(q => q.Questions != null)
                    .SelectMany(q => q.Questions);
            
if(questions == null)
return null;

IEnumerable<IAnswerRow> answerRows = questions
                    .Where(q => q.AnswerRows != null)
                    .SelectMany(q => q.AnswerRows);

if(answerRows == null)
return null;
```

I was interested by Jon's comment about `Enumerable.SelectMany` and Null..
so I wanted to try my example with some fake data to more easily see where the error is, please see the below, specifically how I am using `SelectMany()` on the result of a `SelectMany()`, its clearer to me now that the problem was having to make sure you don't use `SelectMany()` on a null reference, obvious when I actually read the `NullReferenceException` name :( and finally put things together.

Also while doing this, I realised that the use of `try { } catch() { }` in this example is useless and as usual Jon Skeet has the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998566/unhandled-exception-in-try-catch)  :) deferred execution..

so if you want to see the exception for row 2, comment out the relevant row 1 bits :P, sorry I couldn't figure out how to stop this error without re-writing the code example.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SelectManyExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var questionGroupList1 = new List<QuestionGroup>() {
                new QuestionGroup() {
                    Questions = new List<Question>() {
                        new Question() {
                            AnswerRows = new List<AnswerRow>() {
                                new AnswerRow(),
                                new AnswerRow()
                            }
                        },

                        // empty question, causes cascading SelectMany to throw a NullReferenceException
                        null,

                        new Question() {
                            AnswerRows = new List<AnswerRow>() {
                                new AnswerRow() {
                                    Answers = new List<Answer>() {
                                        new Answer(),
                                        new Answer()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var questionGroupList2 = new List<QuestionGroup>() {
                null,
                new QuestionGroup()
            };

            IEnumerable<AnswerRow> answerRows1 = null;
            IEnumerable<AnswerRow> answerRows2 = null;

            try
            {
                answerRows1 = questionGroupList1
                    .SelectMany(q => q.Questions)
                    .SelectMany(q => q.AnswerRows);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine("row 1 error = " + e.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                answerRows2 = questionGroupList2
                    .SelectMany(q => q.Questions)
                    .SelectMany(q => q.AnswerRows);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("row 2 error = " + e.Message);
            }


            Console.WriteLine("row 1: " + answerRows1.Count());
            Console.WriteLine("row 2: " + answerRows2.Count());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }

    public class QuestionGroup {
        public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Question {
        public IEnumerable<AnswerRow> AnswerRows { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnswerRow {
        public IEnumerable<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think your collections would ever be null?

Comment: `questions` and `answerRows` can never be `null`. And in a sane design, `q.Questions` and `q.AnswerRows` probably should never be `null` as well.

Comment: sometimes `if (!question.HasAnswer) return;`

Comment: @Jon Explain why they can never be null. If `QuestionList` is `List<Type>` of length 1, there's no reason I can think of stopping `QuestionList[0]` from being null. Similarly, 'Type' in the my example can still have property 'Questions' uninitialized. i.e. `null`.

Comment: @flem They can never be null because that's how `Where` and `SelectMany` work.  If the input is null they throw an exception, and if it's not null the result will either be a sequence of items, or an empty sequence.  It will *never* be `null`.  As a rule you should avoid `null` values for collections or sequences, just use an empty collection instead.

Comment: It would break if `q` is null, not if `q.Questions` is null.

Comment: @flem: That. Also `questions[0]` does not compile because `questions` is not an `IList`. And even if it did, that's not the same as `questions`.

Comment: In my case the problem is with posted form values and model binding to this existing structure, in one case the model binder ignores a question entirely when its answers are not filled in, a specific check box list case... I would much rather they were always not null.. but regardless of the example I wanted to know more about how to use .Where and .SelectMany together.

Comment: What flavor of LINQ is this? SQL? Entities? Objects?

Comment: @Jon Am I missing an assumption here. This could be linq to objects, entities, xml, sql. That's not indicated as far as I can see. Where is this definition of `questions`? As far as I can see, it could be anything as long as it implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @flem: `questions` is whatever `Enumerable.SelectMany` or `Queryable.SelectMany` decides to return. And that's guaranteed to be non-null.

Comment: @Jon. That doesn't apply on the `.Where`. `q.Questions` can be any `IEnumerable<T>` including `IList<T>`. Besides `q.Questions[0]` was just to explain my `null` possibility example.

Comment: @flem `q.Questions` is entirely different from `questions`.  C# is case sensitive.  `questions` is a local variable that will *never* be null.  `q.Questions` exists in two contexts, since `q` is re-used as a local variable in two scopes.  In both cases it could be null, but as Jon first said, they really *shouldn't* be null (by convention).

Comment: @flem: Not to mention that of course it also applies to the `Where`. No LINQ method will *ever* return `null`.

Comment: @Servy. I think we're on the same page. I've never been referring to the variable `questions`, only the property `Questions` on parameter `q` in the expression in the initial `.Where`. ;)

Comment: @Jon. As just said, I was never referring to the queries, but rather the expressions.

Comment: @flem Well, Jon was, he made that clear, and you were referring to him, so yes, you were referring to the variable `questions`.  There isn't even any other identifier with the same name.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
survey.QuestionList
    .Where(l => l.Questions != null)
    .SelectMany(l => l.Questions)
    .Where(q => q != null && q.AnswerRows != null)
    .SelectMany(q => q.AnswerRows);
```

I'd recommend you ensure your collections are never `null`. `null` can be a bit of a nuisance if you don't handle it well. You end up with `if (something != null) {}` all over your code. Then use:

```
survey.QuestionList
    .SelectMany(l => l.Questions)
    .SelectMany(q => q.AnswerRows);
```

Comment: I fully subscribed to this advice years back, but now with more modern features in C# we have the wonderful Null Coalesce & Null Check operators so this advice is definitely dated. These new'er null operators make working with nulls very concise as you can have : `var thing = something?.isnull ?? ohNoItsNotBecauseWeHaveADefault;` or even `if (something?.isnull?.canIHaveABoolean() ?? false)`

Comment: @CajunCoding this answer is 10 years old after all. That said, I think the null coalescing operator may have already been around at that time. However, I don't believe that materially changes the answer. It's just a different way to handle the nulls, but the outcome is largely the same.

Comment: Agreed. They both have valid use cases.  But since the Null operators weren't highlighted as a viable option I thought it worthy of a comment (but not necessarily a separate answer)... since I stumbled across this even 10 years later 

Answer (score 23):

A solution that complies with DRY would be to use [the null-coalescing operator `??`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) in your `SelectMany` lambda expression.

```
IEnumerable<IQuestion> questions = survey.QuestionList.SelectMany(q => q.Questions ?? Enumerable.Empty<IQuestion>());

IEnumerable<IAnswerRow> answerRows = questions.SelectMany(q => q.AnswerRows ?? Enumerable.Empty<IAnswerRow>());
```

In both the OP's code and the above code, `questions` and `answerRows` will never be null, so the null checks are not required (you may wish to put `.Any()` checks depending on your business logic). But the above code will also never result in an exception if `q.Questions` or `q.AnswerRows` is null.

Comment: Precisely what I was searching for!

Answer (score 13):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectNotNull<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TResult>> selector)
    where TResult : class
{
    return source.Select(selector)
        .Where(sequence => sequence != null)
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Where(item => item != null);
}
```

This then allows you to do the following:

```
var allAnswers = survey.QuestionList
    .SelectNotNull(list => list.Questions)
    .SelectNotNull(question => question.AnswerRows);
```

Comment: "where TResult : class" — is unnecessary limitation preventing usage of long and int sequences. Last "where" is also not needed, if necessary one can add it 'outside'.

Comment: @greatvovan "one can add it outside" is not true because the extension method returns an IEnumerable<TResult> which has no possibilities to add (or remove)...

Comment: @BernoulliIT greatvovan was referring to adding a call to *the extension method* to the end of a query on the calling side, not to adding items to sequences.

Comment: SelectManyNotNull is more appropriate name, than SelectNotNull

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to use something short and reusable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

And then in code it'll look like:

```
survey.QuestionList.SelectMany(q => q.Questions.OrEmpty())
```